# 9.04 Login Screen for 11.04

Tags: 11.04, login, login-screen

The best login screen ever was the one for 9.04, I can best describe it as one text field and you entered in your user name then pushed enter then it asked for your password. Was a little more secure locally and the background image for the login screen was also pretty rad. Anyone know how to change it?

Comment: have you tried lightdm?

Comment: Yes I remember that. It used to look like this:http://linux.chinaitlab.com/UploadFiles_7565/200902/2009022600092367.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a guide on how to change the login screen background here: http://maketecheasier.com/change-login-and-boot-screen-in-ubuntu-lucid/2010/05/13 and it's also possible to do this using [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/)

I'm not sure if it's possible to revert completely back to the 9.04 login screen since it worked in a different way to the one in 10.10 and 11.04, but it is possible to make it require you to type your user name like in 9.04 by going to Login Screen Settings and unselecting "Show list of users"

[image]

Comment: In particular, 9.04 used the GDM login screen screen but 11.04 uses the Plymouth login screen so the theme for 9.04 won't be directly compatible with 11.04 since they run on different software (hence why they don't share a similar theme in the first place).